# Problem with accents with bclogo

Tags: accents

Sorry if my question is previously answered, but I couldn't find it.

My problem is related with package `bclogo`. All is OK, except that the accents don't render adequately.

The rest of the document is perfect, and has no problem at all.

Comment: which accents are those? Can you include a very small TeX code that doesn't compile properly?

Comment: \begin{bclogo}[
  couleur=azulfondo,
  arrondi=0,
  logo=\bcbombe,
  barre=none,
  noborder=true]{Los acentos}

acentos por todos lados
más acentos

Comment: @percusse he means, based on his comment, the acute accent, `m\'{a}s acentos`

Answer (score 2):

I'm very bad with languages so excuse me if this is not Spanish. <strike>Also I don't know what color `azulfondo` is.</strike> I think it means blue background sorry.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[tikz]{bclogo}
\begin{document}
\begin{bclogo}[couleur=yellow, arrondi=0, logo=\bcbombe, barre=none, noborder=true]{Los acentos} 
acentos por todos lados más acento
\end{bclogo}
\end{document}
```

[image]